# Error in loadNamespace, package not found

Tags: r, installation, install.packages

I started using R. When I try to load the package `Rcmdr`, this error appears

```
Loading required package: RcmdrMisc

Loading required package: car

Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘nloptr’

Error: package ‘car’ could not be loaded
```

Please help me , I need this program for a class in college.

Comment: Install package `nloptr`, as said in the error message.

Comment: Thank you , I could already solve the problem thanks to your help